# Online access to Otzar Hachaim vol. 14

Tags: sources-mekorot, internet, publications

About a century ago there was a monthly Torah publication called Otzar Hachaim ([אוצר החיים](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95%D7%93%D7%94_%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%A0%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9A#%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%97%D7%95%D7%9F_%22%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%A8_%D7%94%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D%22)) put out by [Rabbi Chaim Yehudah Ehrenreich](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95%D7%93%D7%94_%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%A0%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9A). Most of the volumes can be found on Hebrewbooks, but not the particular volume that I'm looking for, no. 14, nor is it available on Otzar Hachochmah. Does anyone know whether it can be found somewhere else online?

Comment: Do you know by any chance the year?

Comment: @Kazibácsi late 1937 or early 1938.